Select the first rows with consecutive dates in Polars
I have a Polars DataFrame containing a monthly dates and a values column. I would like to select only the first rows where the months are consecutive, dropping the rest of the rows. For example, in the table that would be the first 5 rows. I tried to use .group_by_dynamic without success. Any ideas how to do this? Thank you!
from datetime import datetime
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "time": pl.datetime_range(
            start=datetime(2020, 12, 1),
            end=datetime(2023, 12, 1),
            interval="1mo",
            eager=True,
        ),
        "n": range(37),
    }
)

df=df.sample(n=10, seed=0)  
df=df.sort(["time"], descending=False)
df




time:datetime[μs]
n




2021-01-01 00:00:00
1


2021-02-01 00:00:00
2


2021-03-01 00:00:00
3


2021-04-01 00:00:00
4


2021-05-01 00:00:00
5


2022-03-01 00:00:00
15


2022-07-01 00:00:00
19


2023-04-01 00:00:00
28


2023-05-01 00:00:00
29


2023-06-01 00:00:00
30


2023-11-01 00:00:00
35




Would 2020-12-01 and 2021-01-01 be considered consecutive? i.e. Do you want to span years?

yes. span over months and years.

One possibility would be to filter with a boolean expression crafter from Expr.diff and cum_min:
df.filter(pl.col('n').diff().eq(1).fill_null(True).cast(int).cum_min().cast(bool))

For year-month you can do the same, building 12*year+month to be able to compute the diff:
out = df.filter((pl.col('time').dt.year()*12+pl.col('time').dt.month()).diff()
                   .eq(1).fill_null(True).cast(int).cum_min().cast(bool)
               )

Output:
shape: (5, 2)
┌─────────────────────┬─────┐
│ time                ┆ n   │
│ ---                 ┆ --- │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64 │
╞═════════════════════╪═════╡
│ 2021-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 1   │
│ 2021-02-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2   │
│ 2021-03-01 00:00:00 ┆ 3   │
│ 2021-04-01 00:00:00 ┆ 4   │
│ 2021-05-01 00:00:00 ┆ 5   │
└─────────────────────┴─────┘


Thank you for the quick responses.  I am getting this attribute error AttributeError: 'Expr' object has no attribute 'cum_min' for the year-month solution you provided.

@pinpass maybe an old polars version? Wasn't it used to be named cummin?

cum_min for the bool type was added in the latest 1.10.0 release.

Requirements of 'consecutive' months are not entirely clear to me - do we ignore day and year part of the datetime completely and just compare months?
So if you simplify the example a bit, here's how you can get first consecutive rows. I base it on first consecutive values of column n, so you can see the algorithm. You use Expr.shift to get the next value for comparison and then Expr.cum_sum to filter out the rows:
df.filter(
    (pl.col('n').shift(-1) - pl.col('n')).cum_sum() == 1
)

|time:datetime[μs]   |   n|
|--------------------|----|
|2021-01-01 00:00:00 |   1|
|2021-02-01 00:00:00 |   2|
|2021-03-01 00:00:00 |   3|
|2021-04-01 00:00:00 |   4|
|2021-05-01 00:00:00 |   5|

Now, you can easily change it to comparing months
